# Is there a way to make a kill cooldown in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am building a murder mystery type map, and I was wondering if there was a way to make a 25-second kill-cooldown. I am giving the murderer team strength 127. I need this to be where when one person (murderer) kills someone from the other team (innocent), their effect goes away, and after 25 seconds, comes back.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delay or slowly loop commands?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/363578/how-to-delay-or-slowly-loop-commands)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, Cronut also needs to know how to reset the schedule after a kill.

Comment: Let me guess, is it an Among Us map?

Answer (score 1):

## How Can I Do This

Have a command block system check when someone dies. For more info check [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/376604/258509).  (It’s for the bedrock edition but should still work, instead of testfor use /execute if). Obviously change the selector form an @e zombie one to an @a. When someone dies you can then run a command that is to take away the strength. You can then use a comparator and repeaters to make a delay and then give the selected player strength again. A repeater set to 4 ticks gives a 0.4 delay, so use 62 *4-tick repeaters* and 1 *2-tick repeater* for 25 seconds.

## Limitations

If someone leaves the kill cooldown will reset.