# Tracking Kills/Deaths in Minecraft Bedrock

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Since Bedrock only has dummy scoreboards, I'm trying to use command blocks to update the scoreboard.
Is there a way to use /testfor or another command to look for stats like Death? are stats even recorded in bedrock?
Has anyone come up with a good way to track kills and/or deaths on bedrock without using TP or spawn points?

Comment: @ElliotGibbs I can't think of any way to do this without using TP or spawn points, what is your reason for avoiding these methods?

Answer (score 1):

Without using janky spawn point or weird item drop pickup systems, you cannot detect kills or deaths. Keep in mind that spawn points are not a bad detection system, though.
[Related Thread Worth Checking Out](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/376604/258509)